# Is it possible to use async/await syntax for UIActivityViewController's completionWithItemsHandler property?

Tags: async-await, uikit

I have this function:

```
struct Downloader {
    static func presentDownloader(
        in viewController: UIViewController,
        with urls: [URL],
        _ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void
    ) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
                activityItems: urls,
                applicationActivities: nil
            )
            activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { _, result, _, _ in
                completion(result)
            }
            viewController.present(
                activityViewController,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil
            )
        }
    }
}
```

It simply creates a `UIActivityViewController` and passes the `completionWithItemsHandler` as a completion block into the static func.

I am now trying to get rid of all the @escaping/closures as much as I can in order to adopt the new async/await syntax, however I don't know if I can do something here with this.
I started adding an `async` to my function, and realized that Xcode shows `completionWithItemsHandler` with an async keyword, but I really have no idea if I can achieve what I want here.

[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that but you need to write yourself little wrapper over it. So it will look something like that:

```
@MainActor
func askToShareFile(url: URL) async {
    let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
    present(avc, animated: true)
    return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        avc.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, completed, returnedItems, activityError in
            print("Activity completed: \(completed), selected action = \(activity), items: \(returnedItems) error: \(activityError)")
            if completed {
                continuation.resume()
            } else {
                if activity == nil {
                    // user cancelled share sheet by closing it
                    continuation.resume()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, important note here that, from my experimentation as of today (iOS 15.5), I can see completion handler is NOT called properly when, on share sheet, user selects any app that handle our file by copying it (activityType = `com.apple.UIKit.activity.RemoteOpenInApplication-ByCopy`).

If you do some changes - be careful, as you might loose continuation here so please test it yourself too.